# How to send json response to ajax call, with serialized object and html generated from HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, html, ajax, json, html-helper

With C# and MVC, in response to an ajax call made with Jquery, I'm trying to send, as a response, an object that would contain a `List<int>` and some html code, generated with a `HtmlHelperExtension` I wrote.

Previously, I was only sending back the html, so I was rendering the `HtmlHelper` in a partial view and return it. But now I would like to, for example, create an object with 2 attributes,  the list and a string representing the html, serialize that object in Json and send it back in response to the ajax call.

But it seems that, with the exception of using a hack, it is not possible, and not recommended to use a `HtmlHelper` in the Controller.

I was also thinking of forgetting the htmlHelper thing, and just render my html code in a class which would be the exact copy of my current `HtmlHelper`.

Do you think there is a way to put a `List<int>` that is in the Controller, with the html returned from a `HtmlHelper`, in an object and serialize it to send it back to an ajax call in javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC does not nativly support a view to a string, it simply returns it.  However you can create a custom controller, with a method that will permit this.  I picked this code up on the interwebs somewhere - cannot recall where - it does a wonderful job.

```
public class ExtendedController : Controller
{
    public string RenderPartialView(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        this.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And then create the controller as

```
public class MyController : ExtendedController
{
    public ActionResult MyAjaxOp()
    {
        List<int> MyList = new List<int>(); // Populate the list as required
        object MyHelperModel = new object(); // View Model as required
        object rtn = new { html = RenderPartialView("MyHelperView", MyHelperModel), list = MyList}
        return Json(rtn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to place the rendered view into a string and pass that to client.

The above is untested sample code, so modify to your requirements.